# Android - Clear Facebook access token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have a `SettingsActivity` where there are several options including finding Facebook friends and logging out. So when a user chooses to find her Facebook friends, she will be sent to another activity where I let her logging in with her Facebook account and save her access token. And then when she chooses to log out, her access token will be cleared. The problem is,  my `logout` method is not written in the same activity with the one I created the session, so when I tried this:

```
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
```

Logcat points `NullPointerException`. Then I tried:

```
Session.setActiveSession(null);
```

And that doesn't work either (friends of the user logged in earlier are still shown, instead of asking the new user to log in).

So what should I do to clear the obtained token? Thank you in advance.

-EDIT-

I think there's something wrong with the activity which I use to open the session. I followed Facebook's [GraphAPISample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/GraphApiSample) and this is what I have done:

```
public class FacebookFriendsActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcast;
    public static Session session;
    private boolean pendingRequest;
    static final String PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY = "PendingRequest";

    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private FindFacebookFriends task;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private TextView text;
    private Button retryBtn;
    private ListView userLayout;
    private ArrayList<User> userList;
    private FollowAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebook_friends);
        // ... set views 

        session = createSession();
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        showFriends();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (session.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data) &&
                pendingRequest &&
                session.getState().isOpened()) {
            showFriends();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        pendingRequest = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean(PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingRequest);
    }

    private void showFriends(){
        task = new FindFacebookFriends();
        task.execute(session.getAccessToken());

    }

    private Session createSession() {
        Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (activeSession == null || activeSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            activeSession = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(getString(R.string.fb_app_id)).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(activeSession);
            new SaveFacebookId().execute(activeSession.getAccessToken());
        }

        return activeSession;
    }
}
```

When I try putting a `Toast` in `createSession()` to check the state of the created `activeSession`, it always shows that the session is closed. It's weird because the `showFriends()` method is still triggered and even after I delete and install the app again, it still show the same friend list. I'm really confused here.

Comment: How are you opening the session? Are you setting the active session when you open it?

Comment: @MingLi I have edited my question with the code which I used to open the session. Please check it out.

Answer (score 7):

in **Facebook SDK v4** we can log out using

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

note that don't forget to initialize sdk like this

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Facebook SDK v4`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads) you can do the following:

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}
```

You can take a look at the [`LoginManager`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/) class.

Answer (score 1):

**Do like this**

```
try {
Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
} catch (Throwable e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Heyy. tried this. but next time try to 'Login with FB' with diff FB A/c, then it crashes with 'Session made to open already opened state'.. So any idea ??

Comment: Where do you get Session class from?

Answer (score 1):

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);  
}
});

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
@Override
public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
Exception exception) {
session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code for session clear in facebook integration android.

Put below method in your activity and call before the login to facebook.

```
public static void fbClearToken(Context context) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {

        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            //clear your preferences if saved
        }
    } else {
        session = new Session(context);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);

        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            //clear your preferences if saved
    }

}
```

For me it's working...
Hope this is helpful for you...

Comment: which import use for Session?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass session variable through **Parcelable** interface and clear session through
that session variable.
Pass facebook session like this : [Passing a Facebook session across activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558973/android-passing-a-facebook-session-across-activities)

Comment: The Session object is not parcelable, do not pass it that way.