# How to use logged in session when passing from one activity to another

Tags: android

I have two Activities namely, MainActivity and Menu. I use my Main Activity to login to facebook successfully, and have setup the necessary login flow there. However i would like to be able to use the session and state in the Menu Activity. So, to do this i have made use of an Intent and putExtra to send the session over to Menu Activity however i am not sure how to use this session there.

This is my MainActivity(this is where i have the login logic and send session over to Menu):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ....some more login logic is here....

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (session != currentSession) {
        return;
    }

    if ((session != null && session.isOpened())) {
        finish();

        Intent menu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
        menu.putExtra("facebookSession", session);
        startActivity(menu);

    } else if (state.isClosed()) {


    }
}
}
```

and this is the Menu Activity(where i recieve the session sent via Intent):

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {           
        Session.setActiveSession((Session) extras.getSerializable("facebookSession"));
    }

}

}
```

Now, how can i use this passed over session to say "log the user out"
I want to try and do this in Menu Activity when logout button is clicked:

```
logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Log user out by using session i got from MainActivity
            if (currentSession != null) {
                currentSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @Hishalv, What is your question actually? do you mean I cant logout the session in MenuActivity ?

Comment: @JarodLawDingYong, thank you for helping, i am not sure how to use the session that was sent through intent(from mainactivity to menu activity). For example, i have created a logout button with onclick listener and am not sure how to use the session to log user out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I try to answer you here,
since you already have the active session set in your MenuActivity,
In your MenuActivity, you can call like this to logout

```
logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jarod, now i understand how to use the session. I did not add the getActiveSession() method. Thanks for your help. Saved me alot of time.